# Distribution of sample p-values with a known true p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, monte-carlo

N. Taleb in his book [Statistical Consequences of Fat Tails: Real World Preasymptotics, Epistemology, and Applications (Technical Incerto)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10488), page 349 (chapter 19: Meta-distribution of p-values and p-hacking) presents this histogram

[image]

of p-values drawn from a samples with a known true p-value.

> It turned out, as we can see in Fig. 18.2 the distribution is extremely asymmetric
> (right-skewed), to the point where 75% of the realizations of a "true" p-value of .05
> will be <.05 (a borderline situation is 3× as likely to pass than fail a given protocol),
> and, what is worse, 60% of the true p-value of .12 will be below .05.

HERE IS HOW HE DID PRODUCE THE ABOVE PLOT:

```
n <- 30
samples <- replicate(1e4, rnorm(n,.5,1))
mu <- 0.5
test.stat <- rep(sqrt(30), ncol(samples)) * colMeans(samples)/apply(samples, 2, sd)
hist(1 - pt(test.stat, df=n-1))
```

> But how does he get the "true p-value" from here?

In trying to replicate this markedly skewed distribution I drew samples from a standard Gaussian, such that using the population standard deviation of $1,$ the p-value would be exactly $0.11$ every single case. However, since the population standard deviation is most usually unknown, I subjected these samples to a $t$-test. I was surprised to see that if anything the tendency was to  lose power, and get p-values higher than the true one:

```
set.seed(0) 
mu <- 0    # Population mean 
sd <- 1                # True population standard deviation 
n <- 10                # Sample size 
exp.p.value <- 0.11    # Predetermined p valued
# To determine the mean of the sample that will result in this p value:
# 0.11 = 1 - pnorm(mean(sam - mu)/ (sd/sqrt(n))) 
mean.sam <- qnorm(1 - exp.p.value) * sd/sqrt(n) + mu  # Computation of the sample mean.
# Samples as draws from the normal, adjusting the last sample element:
# sam <- c(free <- rnorm(n-1,mean=mu,sd=sd), n * mean.sam - sum(free)) 
pvals <- vector() # Empty vector to collect results 
for(i in 1:1e3){  # Getting 1,000 p-values
# Getting samples with a true p-value as the preset 0.11: 
   sam <- c(free <- rnorm(n-1,mean=mu,sd=sd), n * mean.sam - sum(free))
# t.test for 'greater than':
  pvals[i] <- t.test(sam, alternative='greater')[3] 
} 
pvals <- as.numeric(pvals) 
hist(pvals, xlim=c(0.01,0.4), breaks=10, border=F)
abline(v=exp.p.value)
```

[image]

> I'm sure I misunderstood the idea behind the plot, and I am not simulating it correctly, but where and how?

Comment: All p-values are sample p-values. How are you defining "true p-value"? The plot seems to indicate it's some kind of cross sample mean, but (given the definition of a p-value is about the given sample) why is that in any sense "true"? It seems like Taleb is trying to attach a meaning to a p-value that it doesn't possess.

Comment: @Glen_b I am confused about the math presented in Taleb's book, and I can only clarify that in my simulation, and using a "known" population SD = 1 the Z-test on each sample would yield a p-value of 0.11.

Comment: In every sample ` 1 - pnorm((mean(sam) - mu) / (sd/sqrt(n))) = 0.11`.

Comment: @Glen_b It has been a while since I read [Taleb's paper](https://fooledbyrandomness.com/pvalues.pdf) on the metadistribution of p values, however I seem to recall that he meant by "true p value" is a expectation of the metadistribution of p-values.

Comment: So in essence it's just a transformed effect size?

Comment: Yeah, you could describe it that way. It is a choice of p-value that must have a corresponding effect size.

Comment: @Glen_b The PDF of Taleb's book is immediately downloadable from the link provided above.

Comment: I was hoping to have the context and nonstandard terminology in the question be rendered more stand-alone.

Comment: @Glen_b I was able to get the code for Taleb's plot, and posted it in my question, but I still don't understand how he gets the "true" p-value.

Comment: In the linked book file, what you talk about is in Chapter 19, not 18, from page 345 rather than 315.

Comment: The definition of a "true" p-value is on p.345 of the linked file, but I have to admit it doesn't make sense to me. Particularly I don't see a clear statement of under what distribution the p-values this refers to are computed/simulated. It seems it's not the nominal null hypothesis, but if it isn't, in my view the term "true p-value" is inappropriate. Personally I'd say if the book doesn't define its concepts properly, it is useless.

Comment: @Lewian Is there anything you learn from Taleb's plot?

Comment: @Mathtourist Maybe I didn't read enough of the book to understand. The plot caption refers to "an ensemble with given properties". As long as I don't know what these properties are, it doesn't tell me anything; I don't see this explained in the remainder of Chap 19 either, but maybe somebody who reads the book from the beginning would know?